# Refreshing Google Chrome causes pdo to repeatedly insert data

Tags: php, mysql, google-chrome, http, pdo

Here is my code

```
class DBHelper{
private static $_instance;
private $conn;
private static $options = [
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES "UTF8"',
    //PDO::ATTR_AUTOCOMMIT => false,
];
private function __construct($dsnm,$user,$password){
    try {
        $this->conn = new PDO($dsnm,$user,$password,self::$options);
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo  'Connection failed: '  .  $e -> getMessage ();
        exit();
    }
    return $this->conn;
}

public static function get_db_instance($dsnm,$user,$password){
    if((self::$_instance instanceof self) == false){
        self::$_instance = new self($dsnm,$user,$password);
    }
    return self::$_instance;
}

public function query($sql,$array){
    if(is_array($array)){
        //$sth = self::$_instance->conn->prepare($sql);
        $sth = self::$_instance->conn->prepare($sql);
        return $sth->execute($array);  //return bool
        //var_dump(debug_backtrace());
    }
}

public function row($sql,$array){
    $sth = self::$_instance->conn->prepare($sql);
    $sth->execute($array);
    return $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
}

public function row_array($sql,$array){
    $sth = self::$_instance->conn->prepare($sql);
    $sth->execute($array);
    return $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}

public function rows($sql,$array = ''){
    if(is_array($array)){
        $sth = self::$_instance->conn->prepare($sql);
        $sth->execute($array);
        return $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    }else{
        $sth = self::$_instance->conn->query($sql);
        return $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    }
}

public function rows_array($sql,$array = ''){
    if(is_array($array)){
        $sth = self::$_instance->conn->prepare($sql);
        $sth->execute($array);
        return $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }else{
        $sth = self::$_instance->conn->query($sql);
        return $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }
}

$db = DBHelper::get_db_instance("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=blog5.4;charset=UTF8", "root", "");
var_dump($db->query('insert into wechat (name,siteid,phone) values(?,?,?)',['lelelele','0000',time()]));
```

Then I refresh the Google browser, the mysql database has two identical row
[image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/409Ma.png).

At first I thought it was a bug in my script so I modified it with this connection instead:

```
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=blog5.4;charset=UTF8", "root", "");

var_dump($conn->exec("insert into wechat (name,siteid,phone) values ('lelelele','0000','15996573139')")); //return true
```

Unfortunately, that also inserted two rows, so I searched through a lot of questions/answers and discovered that the Google Chrome plugin caused this problem (json view)
[image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mo6Tt.png)

After disabling it and restarting the Google browser it only inserted one row as it should. Why would this plug-in have this kind of problem? Finally, I checked http request and as expected, there is only one request.

[image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wmFCl.png)

Do you know why this might have this type of behavior?

Comment: _“Finally, I checked http request and as expected, there is only one request.”_ - requests caused by extensions usually don’t show up in dev tools. _“Why would this plug-in have this kind of problem?”_ - how should we know, we didn’t write it, and neither do we know which one specifically you are even referring to ...

Comment: hi,guys,you can try the code in your pc,and install "jsonView jsonViewer json formatter" plug,you will find two datas in databases,